# How do I add commas to the inputs in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, format

I have written an app in Shiny (R).  I am using numericInput for my single-valued input and matrixInput (from shinyMatrix) for my tabular input. I would like the input values to include commas whenever the user enters a value of more than 1,000.  I have tried putting various combinations of format, as.numeric and comma, all of which I use in creating my nice-looking output, around my default input value (=0) to no avail.  Is there a way to have the inputs have commas as well?

Comment: Please show us a minimal exam to include what you have tried and people can help you from there.

Comment: Will do.  This is my first time using Stack Overflow, so thank you for letting me know what I need to provide.

My code now is:  

numericInput("extra", 
                     h3("XX"), 
                     value = 0

I've tried 

value = comma(0)
value = comma(as.numeric(0))
value = format(comma(0)) 

and other variations. None of them work.

Thank you for any help you can provide.